kubuntu 24.04 keep freezing
Ever since I upgraded to kubuntu 24.04, I have been experiencing freezes on my laptop. I tried fresh reinstall and I still get the same issue.
I tried booting up to previous kernel but I still freezes up.
I do not see option to report this issue to launchpad when you run ubuntu-bug
I never had this issue on kubuntu 23.10.
I ran sudo journalctl:





UPDATES
I report this issue to launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/2071537
I believe its acpi causes my laptop to freeze like this.
I notice whenever I plug my charger onto my laptop, it will freeze it.
I replicate the issue. this time, I was running sudo journalctl -f | grep 'acpi' to capture the log before my computer locked up.
This was the output:

This was the output when I boot my computer back up:

Update
My laptop froze again. Here are the errors I found this time:
krillavilla@Omen:~$
journalctl -p 3 -xb
Journal file /var/log/journal/851d1be6b61f4acd90c605f9fd5b4e62/system@00061bf712ad6b62-83453c078195276f.journal~ is truncated, ignoring file.
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_E>
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
lines 1-31...skipping...
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
Jul 01 09:19:37 Omen kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
Jul 01 09:19:39 Omen kernel:
Jul 01 09:19:41 Omen kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
Jul 01 09:19:42 Omen kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
Jul 01 09:19:42 Omen bluetoothd[1043]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
Jul 01 09:19:42 Omen bluetoothd[1043]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jul 01 09:20:03 Omen sddm-helper[3855]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 01 09:20:05 Omen systemd[3860]: Failed to start pipewire-input-filter-chain.service - PipeWire Input Filter Chain.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 263 and the job result is failed.
lines 80-127/127 (END)

UPDATE
I added acpi=off to my grub file:
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='Kubuntu'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash acpi=0ff'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"

# If your computer has multiple operating systems installed, then you
# probably want to run os-prober. However, if your computer is a host
# for guest OSes installed via LVM or raw disk devices, running
# os-prober can cause damage to those guest OSes as it mounts
# filesystems to look for things.
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal

I will give updates if this fix my freezing issues.
Update
My laptop freezer again:
MY laptop freezed again. this was the output:
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 263 and the job result is failed.
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_dev_rescan
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/11:2/423/0x00000000
Jul 02 12:46:07 Omen kernel: BUG: workqueue leaked lock or atomic: kworker/11:2/0x7fffffff/423
                                  last function: ata_scsi_...


I refreshed (reset) my laptop again, and it froze completely. I reported to the launchpad Linux team: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2071854 I am all out of ideas

I have deployed Kubuntu 24.04 to several HMI clients at work and am having most of them experience freezing behavior. Looking in to this it seems to be the same issue they had with v22.04. I believe that was due to an issue with MESA library. I am noob with linux so I will look in to this when I can but at work we had to keep production going so we just swapped the clients out with Ubuntu like we were using previously. Can anyone shed some light on this freezing issue with v24.04?
